# Mysql INNODB performance with redundant values in table

Tags: mysql, innodb, redundancy

Please consider a big table with N cols of decimal and M rows.

N could be >50 and M could be > 1000000.

Many many rows will have all the same data, so there is heavy redundancy of tuples (except for id column).

This is the first simple solution

MAIN TABLE

```
+-----+------+------+-----+------+
| id  | col1 | col2 | ... | colN |
+-----+------+------+-----+------+
| 1   | 0    | 0    | ... | 0    |
| 2   | 0    | 0    | ... | 0    |
| ... | ...  | ...  | ... | ...  |
| M   | 0    | 0    | ... | 0    |
+-----+------+------+-----+------+
```

The other solution with two tables could be:

MAIN TABLE

```
+-----+-------+
| id  | refid |
+-----+-------+
| 1   | 1     |
| 2   | 1     |
| ... | ...   |
| M   | 2     |
+-----+-------+
```

REFERENCE TABLE (distinct tuples)

```
+-----+------+------+-----+------+
|refid| col1 | col2 | ... | colN |
+-----+------+------+-----+------+
| 1   | 0    | 0    | ... | 0    |
| 2   | 1    | 0    | ... | 1    |
| ... | ...  | ...  | ... | ...  |
| P   | 0    | 1    | ... | 1    |
+-----+------+------+-----+------+
```

Where REFERENCE TABLE will be joined to MAIN TABLE because it contains all distinct tuples of cols.

My question is: what is the best solution for high performance selecting and summing cols?

```
SELECT SUM(m.col1), SUM(m.col2) ... SUM(m.colN) 
FROM maintable m
```

or with the other structure

```
SELECT SUM(r.col1), SUM(r.col2) ... SUM(r.colN) 
FROM maintable m 
JOIN referencetable r ON m.refid = r.refid
```

Please consider that the second structure may need a big index to find duplicates before insert new rows in REFERENCE TABLE

Comment: If you can do that (or at least consider to do that) depends on your datamodel/the meaning of your data. Assuming id 1 and id 2 have the same values now (so they would have the same `refid`). What should happen to the entries of `id 1` when you change the values of `id 2`? Would you assign a different `refid`?

Comment: This is a good question... I forgot to say that we can considered this table as "history" table, data never changes

Comment: I meant my question more in a more general way. If id 1 and id 2 doesn't have more in common than randomly having the same values, what you are doing is basically compression. You should never do that, it's microoptimitation. Your datamodel should always represent the inner meaning of your data. There are 1000 better ways to speed up your calculation. But to answer your question: you should benchmark it, but I guess it highly depends on how much memory you have. If you don't need too much hdd-buffering to execute the joins (= have enough ram), reading a smaller table from hdd is faster.

Comment: Do the columns contain only 0 or 1, as shown in you example?  (If not _please_ update the example.)

Comment: Are the rows grouped in any way?  A common situation is they are time-oriented and your query would be to sum over one hour.

Comment: Do you really sum over the million-row table without any filtering?  What filtering occurs when using `referencetable`.  Again, I am fishing for some technique to improve the query -- not by tuning or indexing, etc, but by making use of the _rest_ of the data.

Comment: Do you ever `UPDATE` or `DELETE` a row?  (This may lead to "summary" tables.)